# Tuning mysql. Which mysqltuner recommendations should I use?

Tags: mysql, multithreading

Good afternoon.
The site is located on VPS (10 GB RAM, 2 CPU core, 65 GB SSD).
I put mysqltuner and got recommendations for configuring mysql.
I want to clarify which of these recommendations should be applied to get the performance.
And what values to put mysql to parameters?

**Current Mysql settings**

```
    [client]
    port        = 3306
    socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

    [mysqld_safe]
    log-error=/var/log/mysql.log
    pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
    socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
    nice        = 0

    [mysqld]
    local-infile=0
    user        = mysql
    pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
    socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
    port        = 3306
    basedir     = /usr
    datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
    tmpdir      = /tmp
    lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
    explicit_defaults_for_timestamp

    # Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
    # localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
    bind-address    = 127.0.0.1

    log-error   = /var/log/mysql/error.log

    # Recommended in standard MySQL setup
    sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES

    # Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
    symbolic-links=0

    # * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
    #   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
    #
    !includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
    innodb-buffer-pool-instances = 2
    innodb-buffer-pool-size = 2361393152
    innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit = 2
    innodb-log-file-size = 524288000
    innodb-thread-sleep-delay = 0
    join-buffer-size = 8388608
    max-connections = 100
    max-heap-table-size = 268435456
    query-cache-limit = 2097152
    query-cache-size = 67108864
    query-cache-type = ON
    skip-name-resolve = TRUE
    sort-buffer-size = 8388608
    symbolic-links = FALSE
    tmp-table-size = 268435456
```

**Mysqltuner references**

```
     >>  MySQLTuner 1.3.0 - Major Hayden 
     >>  Bug reports, feature requests, and downloads at http://mysqltuner.com/
     >>  Run with '--help' for additional options and output filtering
    [OK] Logged in using credentials from debian maintenance account.
    [OK] Currently running supported MySQL version 5.6.35
    [OK] Operating on 64-bit architecture

    -------- Storage Engine Statistics -------------------------------------------
    [--] Status: +ARCHIVE +BLACKHOLE +CSV -FEDERATED +InnoDB +MRG_MYISAM
    [--] Data in InnoDB tables: 2G (Tables: 326)
    [--] Data in PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA tables: 0B (Tables: 52)
    [--] Data in MyISAM tables: 46M (Tables: 5)
    [!!] Total fragmented tables: 20

    -------- Security Recommendations  -------------------------------------------
    [OK] All database users have passwords assigned

    -------- Performance Metrics -------------------------------------------------
    [--] Up for: 39d 21h 6m 2s (587M q [170.642 qps], 16M conn, TX: 1078B, RX: 358B)
    [--] Reads / Writes: 75% / 25%
    [--] Total buffers: 2.5G global + 16.6M per thread (100 max threads)
    [OK] Maximum possible memory usage: 4.2G (41% of installed RAM)
    [OK] Slow queries: 0% (1K/587M)
    [OK] Highest usage of available connections: 40% (40/100)
    [OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 8.0M/32.6M
    [OK] Key buffer hit rate: 99.5% (136M cached / 677K reads)
    [OK] Query cache efficiency: 81.7% (395M cached / 484M selects)
    [!!] Query cache prunes per day: 1080995
    [OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (473 temp sorts / 27M sorts)
    [!!] Joins performed without indexes: 22423559
    [!!] Temporary tables created on disk: 33% (8M on disk / 25M total)
    [OK] Thread cache hit rate: 99% (158K created / 16M connections)
    [OK] Table cache hit rate: 79% (985 open / 1K opened)
    [OK] Open file limit used: 0% (62/16K)
    [OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 99% (390M immediate / 390M locks)
    [OK] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 2.2G/2.2G
    [!!] InnoDB log waits: 5
    -------- Recommendations -----------------------------------------------------
    General recommendations:
        Run OPTIMIZE TABLE to defragment tables for better performance
        Adjust your join queries to always utilize indexes
        Temporary table size is already large - reduce result set size
        Reduce your SELECT DISTINCT queries without LIMIT clauses
    Variables to adjust:
        query_cache_size (> 64M)
        join_buffer_size (> 8.0M, or always use indexes with joins)
        innodb_log_buffer_size (>= 8M)
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions for your my.cnf-ini [mysqld] from initial available information

```
#sort_buffer_size=8M  # lead with # for default size
#join_buffer_size=8M  # lead with # for default size
thread_cache_size=100  # from autocalc to reduce threads_created of 158K
innodb_buffer_pool_size=3G  # from ~2G  for growth and only 75% available for data
innodb_lru_scan_depth=512  # from 1024 to minimize CPU busy every second
key_buffer_size=64M  # from 8M - you have 32M MyISAM indexes
key_cache_age_threshold=84600  # from 300 seconds to reduce key_reads
query_cache_min_res_unit=512  # from 4096 to increase QC results capacity
innodb_log_buffer_size=16M  # from 8M suggested by Mysqltuner
table_open_cache=2K  # from 1K to reduce tables_opened count
innodb_purge_threads=4  # from 1 to keep up with activity
innodb_flushing_avg_loop=10  # from 30 to keep up with activity
```

research needed to find JOINS with no indexes 22 Million in 39 days are TOO many to be ignored.  EXPLAIN SELECT … will help you find them.

please post progress achieved when time permits.

For additional assistance please find contact information in my profile.

Answer (score 0):

Since we don't know anything about the demands placed on the system by other components on the host, it's impossible to advise on tuning any of the memory usage.

The "joins performed without indexes" suggest that you have schema issues. And the proportion of writes is very high suggesting you **may** have more fundamental issues (such as sloppy ORM). You haven't set your long_query_time. Although the proportion of queries reported as slow is small, this is not a very realistic picture given the workload the machine is handling. You should apply a long_query_time of zero and collect data for a while to get a picture of where your performance/capacity problems really like.